# IntelliJ IDEA: How to open all files in a folder, like Sublime Text allows

Tags: intellij-idea

Sublime Text allows you to open a folder from the command line like this: "subl .".  Is there any way to open a folder this way in IntelliJ IDEA?

Answer (score 1):

For example on my computer, Open **CMD**, type command:

```
"E:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.4\bin\idea.exe" "C:\Users\vy\Google Drive\IT-ebooks\Java\SAMS\SAMS - 2012 - Teach yourself Java in 24 hours\chapter5"
```

**Better**: We put `"E:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.4\bin"` to `%PATH%`, then type command:

```
idea "C:\Users\vy\Google Drive\IT-ebooks\Java\SAMS\SAMS - 2012 - Teach yourself Java in 24 hours\chapter5"
```

**Better**: After set bin forlder's IntelliJ IDEA to `PATH` variable, We type `idea` , then drag and drop folder icon to CMD windows, Windows Oprerating System will auto fill path for you. Press **Enter**. Your eyes will thank me!

[image]

Result, all folder as a new project in IntelliJ IDEA:
[image]

Comment: I'm on a mac, and for some reason when i do this I get an error saying cannot load /path/to/.idea The file does not exist.